# Bertrand's ballot problem - looking for a closed (or say any) formula for $f(n, m)$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, recurrence-relations

While doing some combinatorial counting I found this
recurrence which I do not know how to solve.

$f(n, 0)=1, n \ge 0 $

$f(n, n)=0, n \gt  0 $

$f(n,m) = f(n-1, m) + f(n, m-1), for \ n \gt m \gt 0 $

I did all sorts of things I could think of.
I think it can be expressed with some binomial coefficients
(of $n$ and $m$ of course).

Comment: I'm guessing that  $f(n,m)=0$ for $m>n$. Is it right?

Comment: IMO it is not well-defined: By the first equation $f(0,0)=1$ and by the second $f(0,0)=0$.

Comment: Assume that we care only about values n > m. We definitely don't care about f(0,0)

Comment: Can you edit the question then, as the recurrence is now meaningless

Comment: @gammatester First formula takes priority then second then third.

Comment: If $f(0,0)=1$ to remove the contradiction, then the recurrence looks like the one for NE lattice paths which stay strictly below the diagonal. This can be dealt with by using André's reflection principle.

Comment: @BillO'Haran Yes, we can assume that.

Comment: In fact turns out that I've been solving this problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem (I din't know its name until now, I originally found it in a book as "the votes problem"). I didn't do any googling and I have nowhere to get hints from. So I was able myself to transform this problem to the problem of counting these paths in a lattice which stay strictly below the diagonal (which @N. Shales talks about). And when counting these paths I got my recurrence. Is my recurrence correct even? I am pretty sure it is, I confirmed it for quite a lot of $(n, m) $ couples.

Comment: @peter.petrov: Yes, this is an equivalent problem. It is important that we are careful to say that lattice paths are *strictly* below the diagonal.  There is a similar problem of lattice paths that stay *weakly* below the diagonal which are counted by [Catalan's triangle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_triangle). The problems can both be solved using the reflection principle but the latter requires an additional coordinate shift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK... thanks for all the hints posted as comments.

After reading the Wikipedia article on "Bertrand's ballot theorem" (and especially Andre's proof), I finally found what the closed formula is and I was able to verify that it satisfies my recurrence equations. It is this one.

So turns out I was on the right track with these recurrence equations after all.
But yeah... there's no way I could have inferred this closed formula from them by myself.

${n+m \choose m} - 2 \cdot {n+m-1\choose m-1} $

Now I am just side thinking... I wonder if in general there's any way of finding/inferring such closed formulas just from the recurrence equations (i.e. without any combinatorial thoughts/arguments).